# printing function output correctly

Tags: r, function, loops, printing, output

I wrote this function to find starting values for a nonlinear regression. I have tested the loop in it and it works perfectly, along with the search for the smallest RSS in the list. However, when I put all the code in a function, the results printed are those from the first iteration, not the ones I need.

Does anyone know why this might happen? I don't know if it has to do with printing the list at the end of the function.

```
LSTR1_val <- function(series, linear, nonlinear, trans){

linear <- c (0,linear)

  linear_list           <- lapply (linear, function(i) lag(series, k=-i))
  linear_dat            <- na.omit(do.call(cbind, linear_list))
  colnames(linear_dat)  <- paste0 ("lag_",linear)

  nonlinear_list           <- lapply (nonlinear, function(i) lag(series, k=-i))
  nonlinear_dat            <- do.call(cbind, nonlinear_list)
  colnames(nonlinear_dat)  <- paste0 ("nl.lag_",nonlinear)  
  nonlinear_dat            <- window (nonlinear_dat, start=start(linear_dat),end=end(linear_dat))

  trans       <- window (trans, start=start(linear_dat),end=end(linear_dat))
  scale       <- sqrt   (var(trans))
  grid        <- list()


  lin_eq                <- paste0("lag_0 ~",  paste(paste(colnames(linear_dat)[-1]), sep="",collapse='+'))      
  nonlin_eq             <- paste0("transition + ",paste("I(transition*",paste(colnames(nonlinear_dat),")"), sep="",collapse='+'))

for (c1 in seq(0.97*min(trans), 0.97*max(trans), mean(trans)/5)){
  for (gamma in seq(1,100,2))                                    {

    transition  <- (1+exp(-(gamma/scale)*(trans-c1)))^-1

    grid.regre <-lm(paste0(lin_eq,"+",nonlin_eq),data=data.frame(linear_dat,nonlinear_dat,trans)) 

    coef  <- grid.regre$coefficients
    RSS   <- sum(grid.regre$residuals^2)
    grid[[length(grid)+1]] <- c(RSS,gamma,c1,coef)  
  } 
}

Small_RSS         <- which.min(sapply(grid, "[[", 1))  
Start_val         <- grid[[Small_RSS]]
names(Start_val)  <- c("RSS","gamma","c1",c("intercept",colnames(linear_dat)[-1],"nl_intercept",colnames(nonlinear_dat)))

Resultados <- list(Recomendacion= "Use los valores iniciales:",Ini_val=Start_val)
print(Resultados)

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with your context, but from your codes, it is very likely that something went wrong here:

```
grid.regre <-lm(paste0(lin_eq,"+",nonlin_eq),data=data.frame(linear_dat,nonlinear_dat,trans))
```

Note you write `RSS <- sum(grid.regre$residuals^2)`, and you said `RSS` does not change after each iteration. This means `grid.regre` does not change after each iteration. From above, I further narrow down to

```
data.frame(linear_dat,nonlinear_dat,trans)
```

Should the `trans` here be specified as `transition` as you calculated in the previous step? Note that `transition` varies for each iteration since the variable `c1` in the outer loop changes. Therefore, try to figure out if the `data.frame` is different for each iteration.

Comment: Hi alittleboy. Thaks for your help. I can tell you that the loop works fine. If I take the code from the definition of linear, to Start_val, and run it i get the smallest rss. I get the problem when trying to put the code in the function and trying to print the results.